# Restrict API calls made from particular mobile app?

Tags: security, authentication, mobile-application

I am using php as a backend language. Also i am working for API 2.0, we have already well developed apps for iphone, ipad and android.

For the API v1, i've a shared static secret in both client/server which (secret + time stamp) is always sent by client as get request and server side which is verified always.

This is of course not a secure way to authenticate particularly my app is sending the request.

I saw there are lots of related questions about this, but i found no help out of them. So here i am posting it again.

I want some nice solutions for this.

Comment: Your question could be a little bit more detailed. "Restrict API calls made from particular mobile app?"is not a good description of a problem. You could start by telling us what programming language you use... if any...

Comment: API 2.0? What's that? Do you use angularjs for the app? Java? C#?